# WooCommerce: Set attribute value from custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Disclaimer: I'm new to WooCommerce. If my approach or my terminology in general is flawed, please advise :)

What I want to do: The customer should be able to select a date for his booking on the product page. After adding the product to the cart, the date should be shown in the cart.

My approach so far: I have created a product attribute with the slug arrivaldate and gave it a default value ('Not selected yet'). The attribute has been added to the product, and configured it to be hidden on the product page but be visible on the checkout page. Afterwards, I created a custom field in functions.php to be shown on the product page, and used a jquery datepicker. So far so good.

Using the hook woocommerce_add_cart_item_data, I can set the cart item data this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_cart_item_data', 10, 2 );
function add_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id ) {

    write_log("adding item to cart, setting arrival date to " . $_POST["arrivaldate"]);

    $cart_item_data[ "pa_arrivaldate" ] = $_POST["arrivaldate"];  

    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Yet, I suppose this is not the correct way to set the attribute value, as the line on the checkout page is still filled with the default value.

How can I get this to work? Can I even set attributes to values that have not been created before-hand?

Answer (score 0):

to save value on the order at checkout, you can do like that :

```
add_action("woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta", function ($order_id, array $data) {


    $order = \WC_Order_Factory::get_order($order_id);


    // to associate a different value at each item
    foreach ($order->get_items("line_item") as $id_line_item => $element) {

        update_post_meta($id_line_item, "date", $date);

    }


    // or if the date is associated to the order
    update_post_meta($order->get_ID(), "date", $date);


}, 10, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've been trying this and added a log statement, but I'm afraid the hook is not executed when adding the product to the cart?

Comment: you say that the customer choose a date in the checkout then the date doesn't exist when the product is added to cart ?

Comment: Sorry, I just re-read my question and I didn't phrase it clearly. I want the customer to select a date on the product page, and his selection should carry over to the cart and checkout process once the product is added to the cart.